# phpexcel calculate formulas before saving sheet

Tags: phpexcel

If I save a phpexcel document in Excel5 format that contains values only, people that reference the document can open and close it without issue.

But if I put some formulas in cells, I have two undesired outcomes.

Just before saving the document I set the column widths based on the contents of the columns. Since the formulas have not been calcuated, the columns appear to be only as large as the largest single value in the column so the width is set too narrow. Once the =sum() formulas are calculated after being opened in excel, the contents overflow the cell width and display as a string of ###.

The second effect is that when the total is calculated by excel, the book is marked as modified by excel. When the user attempts to exit the book, they are prompted to see if they want to save their changes. This is disconcerting because in their mind they have not changed anything and annoying because it is an interuption that they really don't want to contend with.

I have been searching the documentation. I found a reference to $objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(true) but it does not help with either issue.

Comment: I am not a master of PHP excel... but in vba you can calculate formulas explicitly using `Calculate` or `Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic` you won't be able to use this directly in PHP (I guess) but hopefully it will put you on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a column is set to AutoSize, PHPExcel attempts to calculate the column width based on the calculated value of the column (so on the result of your SUM() formula), and any additional characters added by format masks such as thousand separators. By default, this is an estimated width: a more accurate calculation method is available, based on using GD, but this is a much bigger overhead, so it is turned off by default. You can enable the more accurate calculation using

```
PHPExcel_Shared_Font::setAutoSizeMethod(PHPExcel_Shared_Font::AUTOSIZE_METHOD_EXACT);
```

If a worksheet contains formulae, then some versions of MS Excel files hold additional information detailing the calculation tree: data that is not saved by PHPExcel (because calculating the tree structure is a big overhead). You don't indicate which format you are using to save your workbooks, or which version of MS Excel you're using to open them; but this is the normal explanation for any prompting to save changes when a PHPExcel-generated file is opened in MS Excel.

Comment: We are opening the files with Excel 2003 SP3.

As stated in the first line of the original post, I am saving in Excel5 format.
This is the writer that I use:

 $objWriter=PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel,'Excel5');


If switching writers will avoid the prompts to save changes it would make my users quite happy. Is there a better output option for me given that the company is stuck with Office 2003 for the foreseeable future?  Where can I read documentation on what  $objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(true|false); does?

Comment: @TedCohen Completely unrelated: Why are you stuck with Excel 2003? Is it because you are opening a deprecated file format such as WK3, WK4 etc...? We are stuck in that rut, but I have fun getting us out.

Comment: It is an economic and a practical decision by the owners of the company. There are practical advantage to have the entire company on one image. And it is very expensive to upgrade the entire company every time Microsoft wants a cash infusion. 2003 does everything we need. Mark explained the reason for what was happening. It was due to an optimization to the writer that I was unaware of.

Comment: @MarkBaker: I have the same issue with formulae (using an `Excel2007` writer and opening the file with Excel 2013). Is there a way to avoid the prompting for save ?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me if you paste it just before saving the file, like this:
$objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(true);
$objWriter -> save("file.xlsx");